# The audio does not play on the voice channel

Tags: discord.js

The bot connects to the voice channel, but there is no sound. Here's my code status.

I've tried many ways, but it's the same reaction over and over again. I need your advice

```
const { createAudioResource, createAudioPlayer, joinVoiceChannel, NoSubscriberBehavior, AudioPlayerStatus, generateDependencyReport, getVoiceConnection, VoiceConnectionStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');

module.exports = {
  name: "play",
  async execute(message, args, client ) {
    arguments = args.shift(2)
    
    ///const arguments = args.shift(1)
    ////console.log(arguments)
   
      const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
          channelId: message.member.voice.channelId,
          guildId: message.guildId,
          adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
          
      })


      const player = createAudioPlayer()
      const resource = createAudioResource('../music/123.mp3')


      player.play(resource, {seek: 0, volume: 1.0})
  
await wait(5000)
console.log("time")
connection.destroy();
  }
}
```

and pakage

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^1.2.0",
    "@discordjs/opus": "^0.8.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^1.1.0",
    "@discordjs/voice": "^0.11.0",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.37.8",
    "discord.js": "^14.3.0",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^5.1.0",
    "libsodium-wrappers": "^0.7.10",
    "ms": "^2.1.3",
    "node.js": "^0.0.1-security",
    "redis": "^4.3.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you did not subscribe to the connection.
You should do:

```js
      const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
          channelId: message.member.voice.channelId,
          guildId: message.guildId,
          adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
          
      })


      const player = createAudioPlayer()
      const resource = createAudioResource('../music/123.mp3')


      player.play(resource, {seek: 0, volume: 1.0})
      connection.subscribe(player);
```

And if you want to destroy the connection after the resource ended, You can use the `idle` event:

```js
const {AudioPlayerStatus} = require('@discordjs/voice');
    player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
      connection.destroy();
    });
```

Comment: thank so much!!! you are great!! i't working!